# Carousel's image is bigger I expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Carousel's image is bigger I expected.

**My Code**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.title {
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0px 5px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.first {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

html,
body,
.menu {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.relative {
  position: relative;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

li a img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.float-right {
  width: calc(100% - 500px);
  overflow: hidden;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<div class="menu" id="menu">
  <h2 class="title first">SITE</h2>
  <ul class="">
    <li><a class="home" href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="profile" href="">Detail</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="imgArea float-right" id="carousel">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="photo1.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="photo2.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script src="carousel.js"></script>
```

when I run this web site,carousel's image is bigger than the original image like yellow arrow in picture.(It does not show image...)
[image]
I wanna put carousel in browser remaining of area of  and carousel's image's size is adjusted 100% in the area.
So I really cannot understand why carousel's image is zoomed.When I wrote in html like `<a href="#"><img src="photo1.jpg" width="100px" height="100px" alt="">` same situation happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the css you have provided:

```
li a img{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;}
```

you need to change it too

```
li a img{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;}
```

Also as you are already using bootstrap u may want to look into bootstrap's carousel https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.main-container {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.header {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
}

.imgArea {
  float: left;
  width: 75%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main-container">

    <div class="header">SITE</div>

    <div class="sidebar" id="menu">
      <ul class="sidebar-ul">
        <li><a class="home" href="">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="profile" href="">Detail</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>


    <div class="imgArea" id="carousel">
      <ul class="carousel-ul">
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="" /></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="" /></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>

  <script src="carousel.js"></script>
</body>
```

Right now i dont have your carousel.js so i hope this will work.

Comment: thx ur comments.I wanna become the image size is remaining of `<div class="menu" id="menu"> `.So how should i write in css?What size of width&height should I write in css?

Comment: First of all you should provide a main container which has both #menu div and #carousel div then give them both float left and provide a width to the menu div and provide carousel div the remaining width using calc.

Comment: thx ur comments.I can understand ur message vacantly only.Would you write ur intended code in ur answer?